# Upload image in CKEditor and replace base64 with generated URL

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ckeditor

I have a problem with CKEditor. When the user paste an image with CTRL-V in the editor, I want to upload the image on the server, and replace all the base64 text in the src attribute of the image with the URL generated on the server.
I tried to upload the image in this way:

```
edit1.on('paste', function (evt) {
    var data, name;
    var copiedImage = evt.data.dataTransfer._.files[0] || null;

    if (copiedImage && copiedImage.type.search('image/') > -1) {

        data = copiedImage;
        name = copiedImage.name;
        
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
            fd = new FormData();

        fd.append('file', data, name);
        fd.append("upload_type", "ticket_image");
        xhr.open('POST', 'uploadHandler.ashx', true);
        xhr.onload = function (e) {
            var response = xhr.response;

            if (response.indexOf('ERROR') != -1) {
                onAttachmentError(response);
            }
            else {
                setTimeout(onUploadedImage(response), 1000);
                
            }
        }
        xhr.send(fd);

    }
}
```

This is the onUploadedImage called after the server method returns:

```
    function onUploadedImage(response) {
        var oFCKeditorDesc = CKEDITOR.instances.txtDescription;
        if (oFCKeditorDesc) {
            description = oFCKeditorDesc.getData().trim();
            if (response) {
                var objResp = JSON.parse(response);
                var dom = document.createElement("DIV");
                dom.innerHTML = description;
    
                $(dom).find("img[src*='base64']").each(function () {
                    setTimeout($(this).attr('src', objResp.url), 1000);
                    
                });
    
                oFCKeditorDesc.setData($(dom).html());
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the server method that uploads the image on the database, and generates a servlet link to download the image

```
 private string ProcessTicketTextImage(HttpContext context)
{

    string fileAlias = context.Request.Files[0].FileName;
    string fileName = string.Format("{0}{1}", string.Format("img_{0}", Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", String.Empty)), Path.GetExtension(fileAlias));
    string src = "";
    string _imageservlet = helpsi.framework.core.Configurator.Instance.getAppSettingsValue("IMAGE_DOWNLOAD_SERVLET");

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_imageservlet))
    {
        byte[] fileData = null;
        using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(context.Request.Files[0].InputStream))
        {
            fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(context.Request.Files[0].ContentLength);
            helpsi.framework.core.Common.Attachment att = new helpsi.framework.core.Common.Attachment();
            att.DATE_LASTMODIFIEDDATE = DateTime.UtcNow;
            att.DESC_FILENAME = fileName;
            att.DESC_CONTENTTYPE = context.Request.Files[0].ContentType;

            att.DESC_CONTENT = Convert.ToBase64String(fileData);
            att.VALO_CONTENTLENGTH = context.Request.Files[0].ContentLength;
            byte[] bodyContent = fileData;
            long IdAttach = helpsi.framework.core.Common.Attachment.SaveAttachment(att, bodyContent);
            if (IdAttach > 0)
                src = string.Format(_imageservlet, IdAttach.ToString());
        }

    }
    
    string _atchHTML = "{\n " +
    "    \"uploaded\": 1,\n" +
    "    \"fileName\": \"" + PageUtil.jsonString(fileName) + "\",\n" +
    "    \"url\": \"" + PageUtil.jsonString(src)  + "\"\n" +
    "}";
       
    return _atchHTML;
}
```

The upload of the image works, the problem is that sometimes if I paste different images, the last image url is replaced in all the src attribute of the pasted images, even if the Xhr request is asynchronous: I tried with setTimeout before replace the image src, but it doesn't work. How can i solve this? Thanks